# Reference a Silverlight Assembly from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have a .net assembly referencing a Silverlight assembly.  The silverlight assembly defines an interface that uses IQueryable.  I want to implement this interface in the .NET assembly, but it says I am not implementing the IQueryable method (even though I am).  I think this is happening because the interface is using the silverlight IQueryable and the implementation is using the .net IQueryable.  Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your interface explicitly for .Net without referencing Silverlight library.
If you want to reuse the code between Silverlight and .Net you can use linked files in VS (see [Sharing Code Between .NET and Silverlight Platforms](http://pagebrooks.com/archive/2008/10/11/sharing-code-between-.net-and-silverlight-platforms.aspx) post).

HTH

Comment: The link is dead. Please try to include as much as possible of the answer in the text.